# Send 2 json from server to angularjs controller by 1 request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

In a rails project, I have 1 controller and 2 model. I want send 1 request from `angularjs` to rails server and for response, get 2 json array, 1. first model. 2. seccond model.

Now I use below code, and get just 1 of 2 array:

Rails Contorller: `tables_controller.rb`:

```
class Api::V1::TablesController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def index
    @table = Table.all
    @mostagheltype = Mostagheltype.all
    //I can just send 1 of model.
    respond_with(Table.all)
  end
end
```

Angularjs Controller: `table.js`:

```
$scope.tables = Tables.index();
```

`tableService.js`:

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('tableService', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('Tables', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/tables.json', {}, {
        index: { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    });
});
```

I can push 2 table in 1 array in rails controller and then recieve this from angular controller, like below:

```
array = []

Table.all.each do |table|
  array << { name: table.name, check: 1 }
end
Mostagheltype.all.each do |m|
  array << { name: mostagheltype.name, check: 2}
end
//I can seprate 2 array by `check` value in angularjs part.
```

but I want a solution that I send each array separate. How can I do this? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no. You can't have two responses to one request. You can respond with an object that contains both arrays.

My is a little rusty. So this may be more psuedo code than ruby;

```
obj  = {} 
obj.array1 =[] 
obj.array2 =[]
```

Then populate each array and return the object.

Comment: This guide is similar to my solution that I describe end of question. I set new route and get seccond array by use route, but I search for a clear solution to get objects with send 1 request.